# Separate number from the fullnames in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having a table with full name column, but the data in the column also has number attached with it , I need to separate those two in two different columns. This is one example .

```
create table #Test (ID int, name varchar(50))
insert into #Test values
(1, 'Alice,king (00123)'),
(2, 'John,Maxweell (00226)'),
(3, 'Marry,botam (1226)')
```

From above table I want `fullname` in one column and the `number` in new column .any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are numbers always inside brackets?

Comment: What database are we talking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution will work if the numbers in the column are always in `()` and if there is only one occurrence each of `(` and `)`.

```
select 
 substring(name,1,charindex('(',name)-1) as name
,substring(name,charindex('(',name)+1,charindex(')',name)-charindex('(',name)-1)  as num
from tablename
where charindex('(',name) > 0 and charindex(')',name) > 0
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that this assumes that the column only ever has one '(' or ')' (probably a good assumption for names?)

Comment: Numbers are always in ().   vkp from your query i am still getting ) in the end of the number. how can we remove this